# How do I sum all of the pay?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

How do I sum all of the pay in my code?

```
for i in range (n):
   
    if hrs[i] >=0 and hrs[i]<=40:
        pay = (h[i] * 9.5)
   
        
    elif hrs[i] >40 and hrs[i]<=59:
        pay = 380 +(h[i] - 40) * 9.5 * 1.5
          
    else :
        hrs[i] >60
        pay = 665 + (h[i] - 60) * 9.5 * 2.0
   
        
    print ('{:3d}        {:15s}{:3d}      {}   '.format (i+1,name[i],hrs[i],pay,))
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what _specifically_ went wrong with your attempts?

Comment: `hrs[i] >60` this line does absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```py
total = 0

for i in range(20):
    pay = 0
    if hrs[i] >=0 and hrs[i]<=40:
        pay += (h[i] * 9.5)
    elif hrs[i] >40 and hrs[i]<=59:
        pay += 380 +(h[i] - 40) * 9.5 * 1.5
    else :
        pay += 665 + (h[i] - 60) * 9.5 * 2.0

    total += pay

    print ('{:3d}        {:15s}{:3d}      {}   '.format (i+1,name[i],hrs[i],pay,))
```

The line `hrs[i] >60` isn't necessary as it doesn't do anything so I would recommend removing it!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i appreciate it very much. Right now when i play the program it goes like this .

 No    Name        Hours   Salary (RM)
  1        Nik            10      95.0   
  2        Yan           45      451.25   
  3        Li               20      190.0   
  4        Azman       50      522.5   
  5        Nikah         40      380.0   
  6        Putri           63      722.0   
  7        Azmi          68      817.0   
  8        Azie           52      551.0   
  9        Sofiya        50      522.5

Now how can i sum up all the salary??

Comment: How does it go? Also, please note that in the for loop changed it to `in range(20)`. You might want to change it back to `in range(n)`

Comment: See the edited code.

Comment: I already fix the range. it shows all the list that i wanted. now i just want to know how do i sum the pay in the list into 1 answer. i really appreciate your help

Comment: hai the pilot dude. i posted my other problem below my question. can you check it out. i appreciate it

Comment: Hey. Sorry but I can't exactly see your second question. Where is it?

Comment: ahh i cannot see it either lol. is there any ways that i can contact you?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure sorry!

Comment: hai, i just edited my answer. it would help a lot if you can check at out. Thanks again and sorry for bothering

Comment: No problem and it's fine. Which question did you edit

Comment: ahhh it need some approval from trusted community member. i just ask here. The output is great, Just as expected. Salary (RM) :95.00 , 100.00 ,150.00. now how do i sum up all of the salary???. The salary is the pay one.

Comment: You could add `total += pay` just before print

Comment: it works. Bro thank you very much for your knowledge. May you have a good day

Comment: It's good that it worked. No problems and I hope you have a good day too!

Comment: @ThePilotDude I have a question, what is the following line of code for:  `hrs[i] >60`?

Comment: @eyllanesc To answer your question, there is no point in that line. I simple kept it in for the users benefit so that the user wouldn't get confused as to why there is a missing line.

Comment: @ThePilotDude So it wasn't enough to turn it into a comment?

Comment: @eyllanesc Someone else had already said that. Besides you didn't point it out. I answered the question and I answered it well. That's the main point.

Comment: @ThePilotDude In SO we not only seek to solve the problem of the OP (which is often trivial) but also to have a collection of quality Q&A, and my observation is precisely in that direction. Please read [ask] and [answer]. That is the same observation I made to you in the other post: Make sure everything you say is correct, explain what the OP's error is, provide clear and quality code, etc.

Comment: @eyllanesc I did fix it and everything I said was correct. I simply forgot something and am now getting heavily penalised for it. Why didn't you mention it then

Comment: @eyllanesc I said you are penalizing me. There are much nicer ways to comment such as, "By the way, that line isn't necessary and you should remove it." Please read [How to Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). It says: Comments are not recommended for any of the following:

Suggesting corrections that don't fundamentally change the meaning of the post; instead, make or suggest an edit

Comment: wow guys, don't fight please. I am like literally just learn to code and very new to stack overflow i did't even knew my ways around yet. @ThePilotDude did a very great job in helping me out.